# With AVSpeechSynthesizer can you change the way words or phrases are spoken?

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

Are there any methods or undocumented tricks for changing the way words or phrases are spoken by the AVSpeechSynthesizer? I am not asking about changing the pitch of the entire sentence or the rate at which it is spoken. I am wanting to change the voice inflection or the intonation of certain parts of a sentence.

If not, what are some SDKs or APIs that do allow for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `AVSpeechUtterance` allows you to set the rate, pitch, etc. You can create small utterances for, say, each word, and pass those to an `AVSpeechSynthesizer`, which maintains a queue of utterances to speak. (In other words, you can call `speakUtterance:` for all of your utterances and it will say them one after another.)

For an example of this technique, check out [this blog post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64623/make-narrated-book-using-avspeechsynthesizer-ios-7). Note that the level of control here is not great; you can't really control inflection, for example, but you can control pauses, pitch, and so on on a per-word basis.